# Custom home page with block and jqDock

Tags: 7, theming

I'm a newbie in Drupal, and I have a really important web site to build. I've started with a Zen template, so I can build the entire theme from scratch.

I've looked around for better practices and best ways to do this, and finally decided to start by doing the "Master-Layout" on the "page.tpl.php" (I've figured that it's the best place for the global website structure), plus, I'm using the default CSS's files do arrange the things on the page.

But now, I need to start the "home page" content section. It will have a few "blocks"  and I still have some things that isn't clear what I can do to build this way.

For example, I have a "News" structure, that the authors use it to insert the news articles. I need to list the news on the home page much like an accordion style, with the image related.

Other example, the site will have a dynamic menu, using a jQuery plug-in like this: http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/, and each item on this dock, will come from the Drupal database. Should I create a modulo to accomplish this? Can you guys help me??

Comment: Hi Welcome to drupal answers. You question is quite broad. I am sure there are people here who can help you. But if you try to think of smaller questions, see what has been asked before and ask for smaller bits of info you may be able to find help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For home page:

- Clone your page.tpl.php as page-front.tpl.php in order to customized work for your home page.

Listing nodes in accordion:
* Use views to build a list for you
* User [Views Accordion](http://drupal.org/project/views_accordion) to format them in accordion

jqDock menu:
jqDock menu can be build using your content templates. But it should be clear what type of data coming from your database.

For custom data you will have to build your own module to fetch data.

Comment: this template clone should work on Drupal 7? I did this, and the home page content still the same: "No front page content has been created yet."

Comment: I found a -- rule on another question: "page--front.tpl.php"

Comment: I think rules are slightly changed in Drupal7